# Converting a MongoDB query to JSON

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and don't know more than the basics of python and i'm trying to get some data from a MongoDB database, I can get it using this code.
My question is: How can I convert what comes out (I added it here) to json so that I can separate things like name, brithdate, birthday, etc.

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://10.0.0.45:27017/")

mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]

mycol = mydb["birthdays"]


myquery = { "name": "John" }
mydoc = mycol.find(myquery)

for x in mydoc:
  print(x)
```

This is what gets printed in the `for x in mydoc:`

```
data that I get from MongoDB: {u'birthmonth': u'<month>', u'_id': ObjectId('5db3a42431f86884b0746c3e'), u'name': u'<name>', u'birthday': u'<day>', u'birthyear': u'<year>'}
```

And when I just print mydoc I get

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x10a1b4c90>
```

I am not actually getting the <> in the `for x in mydoc:` when I print, I just added them to replace the actual data.

btw I got the code from https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_query.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get by iterating from cursor is python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You dont need to convert it to json and also MongoDB is working with BSONs, what means some fields could be not JSON serializable for example field "_id". To get  values you use something like this:

```
for x in mydoc: 
    print(x['birthmonth'],x['_id'], x['name'], :x['birthday'], x['birthyear'])
```

But if you really want json your code will look something like this:

```
import json
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://10.0.0.45:27017/")

mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["birthdays"]
myquery = { "name": "John" }
#because ObjectId is not JSON serializable
project = {"_id":0}
mydoc = mycol.find(myquery, project)

for x in mydoc:
    print(json.dumps(x))
```